# enviar parametos de php a jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

tengo este código con el que envió una variable a una función en js

```
onclick="preguntaeliminaritemlista(var1)
```

y lo recibo acá:

```
function preguntaeliminaritemlista(var1){

}
```

ahora quiero enviar 2 variables, lo intente de esta manera:

```
onclick="preguntaeliminaritemlista(var1, var2)
```

recibo:

```
function preguntaeliminaritemlista(var1, var2){

}
```

pero me muestra que la variable 2 no esta definida, los dos datos que envió son de tipo numérico

Comment: Por favor, unifica y completa el codigo... no expliques por partes, y agrega lo necesario para el [mre]

Comment: Falta comillas al fin.  onclick="preguntaeliminaritemlista(var1, var2)" Y no veo nada de PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Yo no soy muy fan de pasar las variables directas al js, yo prefiero ponerlas en un elemento:

```
<button data-var1="<?= $var1 ?>" data-var2="<?= $var2 ?>" onclick="preguntaeliminaritemlista(this)">Borrar</li>
```

Y luego obtenerlas desde el js:

```
function preguntaeliminaritemlista(e) {
  var var1 = e.getAttribute('data-var1');
  var var2 = e.getAttribute('data-var2');
  
  // Usamos las variables
  console.log(var1, var2);
}
```

Espero te sirva

Answer (score 0):

Desde php puedes enviar variales a Jquery (Javascript) utilizando el metodo `echo`

De la siguiente manera:

```html
<?php
$variable1 = "Este es el valor de la varable1";
$variable2 = "Este es el valor de la variable2";

echo "<script>
  var var1 = '$variable1';
  var var2 = '$variable2';

</script>";

?>
```

De igual manera en una funcion.

```html
<?php 
  $variable1 = "valor de la variable 1 ";
  $variable2 = "valor de la variable 2 ";
?>

<input type="submit" onclick="preguntaeliminaritemlista(<?=$variable1?>, <?=$variable2?>)/>
```

Nota: aqui utilizo el abreviado de `echo`  que es `<?=$variable?>`  aque podrias escribir `<?php echo $variable; ?>`

Tambien puedes obtener el valor de `var1` y `var2` desde un `js`  externo

Comment: Buena respuesta, solo faltó entrecomillar los valores dentro de la función.